# Need a source for the following result: From $v \in H^1$ and $f$ Lipschitz it follows that $f(v) \in H^1$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, online-resources

I am looking for a source of the following (or a similar) result:

> If $v \in H^1(\Omega,\mathbb{C})$ on a bounded domain $\Omega$ and $f: R(v) \to \mathbb{C}$ is Lipschitz continuous, then $f(v) \in H^1(\Omega, \mathbb{C})$

Here $H^1$ denotes the Sobolev space $W^{1,2}$ and $R(v)$ denotes the range of $v$.

In various answers on StackExchange this is used (e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195697/summability-of-a-function/197265#197265) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430754/i-need-help-understanding-the-proof-of-the-lifting-theorem-for-h1-functions)) and is referred to as a "standard fact".

I can't seem to produce a proof of it and I don't find the result in my books about Sobolev Spaces. Does anybody have a source for it?

EDIT: In my case I can't suppose that $f(0)=0$!

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks. I corrected the mistake.

Comment: @Romeo Do you mean Brezis' "Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations"? I couldn't find it there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easiest to approach this using difference quotients. Let $\tau_h^i u(x) = u(x + h e_i)$ where $e_i$ is one of the standard unit vectors. Define the difference quotient $\Delta_h^iu = (\tau_h^i u - u)/h$.

You need the two propositions:

**Proposition 1** If $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, then for every $\Omega' \Subset \Omega$ with $\mathrm{dist}(\Omega',\Omega^c) > h$, the difference quotient $\Delta_h^iu \in L^p(\Omega')$ and $$\|\Delta_h^i u\|_{L^p(\Omega')} \leq \|u\|_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}$$ is true.

**Proposition 2** If $u\in L^p(\Omega)$ for $p \in (1,\infty)$. If there exists a constant $K$ so that $\|\Delta_h^iu\|_{L^p(\Omega')} \leq K$ for every index $i$ and for every $h > 0$, and every $\Omega'\Subset \Omega$ satisfying $\mathrm{dist}(\Omega',\Omega^c) > h$; then $u$ is weakly differentiable with its weak derivative in $L^p(\Omega)$.

(Those are propositions 16 and 17 in [my lecture notes on Sobolev spaces](http://people.epfl.ch/cgi-bin/people?id=217997&op=bio&lang=en&cvlang=en). Alternatively you can also find them in Section 7.11 of Gilbarg and Trudinger.)

To conclude the proof it suffices to observe that if $f$ is Lipschitz, then

$$ |\Delta_h^i (f(v))| \leq \mu |\Delta_h^i v| $$

where $\mu$ is the Lipschitz constant of $f$.